# redirect_mismatch error / no auth code after updating callback URL for Cognito app client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, redirect-uri

I've done the below:

- I've created a new user pool with 1 app client.
- I've set the callback URL of my app client to `https://my-domain/oauth2/idpresponse`
- I've added Okta as a SAML identity provider for Cognito

When I navigate to `https://my-domain/my-app`, I'm correctly redirected to the Cognito login page. After successful authentication through the Cognito login page, I'm redirected to my application home page.

However, despite `response_type=code` being set in the Cognito URL indicating that an auth code should be appended to my URL upon successful login, this isn't happening.

The page `https://my-domain/oauth2/idpresponse?code=code-I-need` is accessed but then bypassed, leading directly to my application page without the auth code appended.

I attempted to change the callback URL to `https://my-domain/my-app` for my app client, but this resulted in a `redirect_mismatch` error in Cognito. It appears that `oauth2/idpresponse` must be included in the callback.

I manually modified the Cognito URL redirect_uri variable to `redirect_uri=https://my-domain/my-app`, which worked. I landed on my app page with the URL `https://my-domain/my-app?code=code-I-need`.

However, I've had to keep both callback URLs in my app client:

- `https://my-domain/oauth2/idpresponse`
- `https://my-domain/my-app`.

How can I set `https://my-domain/my-app` as the default `redirect_uri` variable in the Cognito URL without having to manually change it?

Comment: It is option B sir!

Comment: So I have both a regular Cognito login option and an Okta login option. Both work, and I see the 'https://my-domain/oauth2/idpresponse?code=1234' in developer console, however it is skipping this page and going straight to 'https://my-domain/my-app' with no code as in the image above. If I manually change the redirect uri in the url to my-app, then login, it works and I land on my app with the code. The default redirect uri can only be set as oauth2/idpresponse in the callback url otherwise I get a mismatch error.

Comment: ok i THINK i am following what you are saying, to break it down, I should remove the idpresponse url from the callback in AWS console and only have my app one. Is there a change I need to make in Okta then? As I did try this and got the mismatch error in the browser? my currect Okta SSO, recipient and destination URL is - https://cognito-domain.authmy-region.amazoncognito.com/saml2/idpresponse, do I need to modify this to include my app domain??

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary unfortunately SO assigned the 100 point bounty to a wrong answer as there were no other on this thread. If we can establish the problem and figure it out I will happily assign a bounty to you afterwards, my hands were tied as the bounty ran out. I am able to continue this in your chat thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: ensure you generate a new URL for logging in via the *View Hosted UI* button after making changes to the callback URL(s) for your app client

---

> I attempted to change the callback URL to `https://my-domain/my-app` for my app client, but this resulted in a `redirect_mismatch` error in Cognito. It appears that `oauth2/idpresponse` must be included in the callback.

There are no requirements for you to have `oauth2/idpresponse` in your app client's allowed callback URLs. As the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/federation-endpoints.html) mention, the `oauth2/idpresponse` and `saml/idpresponse` are endpoints that Cognito uses for handling the responses from OpenID Connect (OIDC) and SAML identity providers (IdPs). They're there to manage the relationship between Cognito & the IdP and have nothing to do with your app client - feel free to remove that callback URL as it's not needed.

The `redirect_uri` mismatch error indicates that the callback URL that was provided to the `/oauth2/authorize` Cognito endpoint, in the form of the `redirect_uri` query parameter, didn't match a callback URL allowed in the app client config.

When using the Cognito hosted UI via the *View Hosted UI* button, the URL is auto generated for you. This URL contains the redirect URL, set to the first (or only) allowed callback URL. When you change the allowed callback URLs (or any other value that is in the login endpoint URL e.g. scopes), you can't just use the old URL and need to re-click the button to generate a new URL.

You're most likely still using the old URL with the `redirect_uri` set to the no-longer-allowed `https://my-domain/oauth2/idpresponse` value and not the new `https://my-domain/my-app` URL.

Make sure that after making changes to the allowed callback URL, you're not just refreshing the old login URL & generate a new URL using the *View Hosted UI* button.

Answer (score -1):

AWS Cognito has the role of an OAuth authorization server. It can integrate with external identity providers (IDPs), such as Google Sign In.

When it does, the external IDP will post its response to Cognito's `/oauth/idp/response` location. This would contain Google's authorization code. Cognito will then process the IDP's authorization code and issue its own authorization code to your app.

Your own app should use a value such as `https://yourappdomain/callback` instead. It will then receive the AWS Cognito authorization code. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/federated-logins/) shows how a federated login works.

You do not seem to need a federated login, so you should not need to configure the `/oauth/idp/response` path. So just changing the redirect_uri to a location within the app feels like the right action.

Comment: As stated, when I removed the https://my-domain/oauth2/idpresponse callback and just had https://my-domain/my-app-callback, I got the error redirect_uri mismatch. What settings can I change/reconfigure to not require the /oauth/idp/response callback, and make my app callback valid please? Pulling my hair out on this one! Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes this can he caused by an extra redirect caused by trailing backslash handling. Eg /app?code=xxx redirects to /app/ and loses the code. I usually use a trailing backslash for the redirect URI, since some tech stacks or web hosts, do the above redirect otherwise.